# How to give auto height to this jquery toggle (show/hide)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/P6vKf/14/

**Updated the jsfiddle link**

In this example I have 3 different modules for show/hide and all have different height to show and hide the items.

```
$(function(){
   $(".more-destination").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().prev("ul").animate({
              height: "500px"
           }, 800, function() {});
          $(this).next(".less-destination").toggle();
          $(this).toggle();
   });

   $(".less-destination").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().prev("ul").animate({
             height: "200px"
          }, 800, function() {});
         $(this).prev(".more-destination").toggle();
         $(this).toggle();
   });
});
```

I want to make the height **auto** for Min-height (default) AND Max-height ( after open) so i can use the jquery code to any container where I need this effect.

Is it possible?

I want to set min-height only in CSS and for height it should take height upon how many items in the div.

I don't want to give any height or width in javascript. in CSS only

Comment: You mean 'auto' for the user window size or 'auto' for content?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, just a bit of hackery. You can clone the element, check it's height, then animate to that height. Reverse for minimising the element.

```
$(".more-destination").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $(this).parent().prev("ul").clone().appendTo('body').height('auto');
    var height = clone.height();
    clone.remove();

    $(this).parent().prev("ul").animate({
        height: height
    }, 800, function() {});

    $(this).next(".less-destination").toggle();
    $(this).toggle();
});

$(".less-destination").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $(this).parent().prev("ul").clone().appendTo('body').height('');
    var height = clone.height();
    clone.remove();

    $(this).parent().prev("ul").animate({
        height: height
    }, 800, function() {});

    $(this).prev(".more-destination").toggle();
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P6vKf/8/

Comment: +1 for the answer. I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/P6vKf/10/ but i think it's not working

Comment: You need to explicitly set the image height using CSS. When the element is cloned, the images have no height for a few milliseconds - enough to mess with the calculation. See: http://jsfiddle.net/P6vKf/11/

Comment: in 2nd module I have more image but only showing few of them on expand

Comment: It seems to be working for me in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Which browser are you using, and have you updated the jsFiddle with any new code?

Comment: OK. working but I cannot fix the image size in CSS http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/P6vKf/14/

Comment: updating the example in question

Comment: Why can't you set the image size using CSS? You either need to set it using CSS, or using img properties (`<img width="100" height="100" />`), otherwise you'll encounter the issue I described above. If you really can't do this, it'll have to be implemented another way.

Comment: because i just used image for an example inside `<li>` but it can be anything only text, text+image , only image, another `div`

Comment: It's only images that will cause the issue, because the height of an image is 0 until the image starts loading (and it has the size data). Any other combination of elements/divs/text won't matter, as long as any images have their own height explicitly set. See: http://jsfiddle.net/P6vKf/15/

Comment: it's working fine if I set `width` and `height` for images in css. http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/6zJjV/4/light/ but don't know in ma actual website it's taking too much height when we open